How to merge timestamp columns with the same name in a single dataframe
I am new to pandas and I currently have a list of .txt files reading into one dataframe. The .txt files contain 2 columns, the timestamp and the associated data. I am writing this code as a "template" code, so important to note that the timestamp column name will vary depending on the .txt files in the list.
I don't want to "drop" any of the columns, as its important that the timestamp column with the most time stamps is used, and where the data is missing in COL_A or COL_B, its filled with NaN. The columns are already NaN where data is missing, but can't seem to figure out how to join the timestamp columns with the same names, based on column with the most timestamps, while also considering this a template code.
Since this is template code, it will not always be the first Timestamp column that has the most time steps, so setting the index to col 1 doesn't seem to work.
current code:
#create dataframe that reads in the first file

    main_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_table(file_list[0])) 

for i in range(1,len(file_list)):

    #reads all the text files in the list

    data = pd.read_table(file_list[i])

    #puts all the text files into a dataframe

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

    #concatenates the read in .txt files to the main_dataframe

    main_dataframe = pd.concat([main_dataframe, df1], axis = 1)`

result:
Timestamp (UTC-06)     COL_A     Timestamp (UTC-06)    COL_B
0    1/27/2017 2:20         1     10/20/2017 9:00       5
1    1/27/2017 2:30         2     10/20/2017 9:10       6
2    1/27/2017 2:40         3     10/20/2017 9:20       7
3    1/27/2017 2:50         4     10/20/2017 9:30       8
Needed Output:
Timestamp (UTC-06)     COL_A     COL_B
0    1/27/2017 2:20         1     NaN
1    1/27/2017 2:30         2     NaN
2    1/27/2017 2:40         3     NaN
3    1/27/2017 2:50         4     NaN
4    10/20/2017 9:00        NaN     5
5    10/20/2017 9:10        NaN     6
6    10/20/2017 9:20        NaN     7
7    10/20/2017 9:20        NaN     8

Can you please [edit] your question and put there other example (with smaller dataframe, without the ...) and expected output (that demonstrates the problem)
